# Link class to multiple other classes

Tags: c++, class

My goal is to use a class inside another class, this would reduce the overall code and improve readability. There is one class that accesses the hardware, and other classes should make use of this class

Here is the harware class:

```
class NFC:NFC(int buspin, int datapin, int resetpin, int cspin, int *param)
```

inside the class is:

```
NFC::getDatablock(uint8_t address, uint8_t *data);
```

Now there are classes "configuration" and "history" that need to read and write data from the NFC class.

Currently my solution is as following:

```
NFC reader(1,2,3,4,x);
CONFIG configuration();

//read configuration from reader
uint8_t configuration[64]={};
reader.getDatablock(3, &configuration);
//transfer data to config:
configuration.importData(&configuration);

//save data
uint8_t newData[64])={};
configruation.getdata(&newData);
//transfer to reader
reader.write(1,&configuration
```

This requiers to add this code in the "main" application, because main.cpp knows about all the classes. It would be more desirable if it would be possible to just call :

```
configuration.getConfig();
```

and inside the function:

```
void configuration::getConfig(){

uint8_t db[64] = {};
reader.getDatablock(3, &configuration);
...
}
```

Its there a way to achieve this?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're asking. You can, of course, use other classes and objects from within a class function, the same way you can from `main`.

Comment: Just pass reader as a parameter to getconfig():


configuration.getConfig(reader);

Comment: Or pass the Reader instance as a parameter in Configuration's constructor and assign to a Private Instanstance Variable. Then no need to send the Reader instance as parameter every function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Options:

Option 1:

You will create a private variable in the Configuration class of type Reader, then add a parameter in the Constructor of the Configuration class that accepts a Reader instance. You can then assign this instance to the private instance variable in the Configuration class.

Then in `Configuration::getConfig()` you can access the Reader instance through your Private Instance Variable.

Configuration.h

```
Class Config {
public:
Config(Reader *reader);
void getConfig();

private:
Reader *_reader;
```

Configuration.cpp

```
Config::Config(Reader *reader){
_reader = reader;
}

void Config::getConfig(){
...
_reader.getDatablock(...)
...
}
```

Option 2:

As stated by @mcabreb you can just send through the reader instance as a parameter in getConfig()

Config.h

```
Class Config{
...
void getConfig(Reader *reader);
```

Config.cpp

```
void getConfig(Reader *reader){
...
reader.getDatablock(...)
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both options work very well. I decided to use option2, since this allows reader to be flexible, and not bound to the config class. If there are multiple readers, it can be adressed dynamically.